# CasperJS continuous run

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a simple CasperJs script, which looks something like this:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

Now, I would like this script to execute in loop until I stop it, hence I tried:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

setInterval(function() {
   casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();}, 5000);
```

But the problem is, `casper.run()` also exits the file execution, without creating a new casper instance. An ugly workaround for my issue, was just creating a bash script which executed my command in a loop. My question is: how can I execute a command in the terminal `casperjs myscript.js` which will run my scraping script continuously, with a sleep of x seconds, till I stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No time to test the following but I have done similar thing before:

```
casper.start();
openPages();

function openPages() {
    casper.thenOpen('http://casperjs.org', function() {
        this.echo('First Page: ' + this.getTitle());
    });

    casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
        this.echo('Second Page: ' + this.getTitle());
    });

    openPages();
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Use `casper.wait()` if you want to wait for certain seconds before the next crawl.

```
casper.wait(5000, function() {
    openPages();
});
```